# Laravel get posts with multiple tags

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I'm working with a laravel `belongsToMany` relationship between `Post` and `Tag`.

What I'm trying to do is get all `Post`s where it has multiple tags.

I've tried all sorts of eloquent queries, but I can't get it at all.

Currently I can get an array of `post_id`'s and `tag_id`'s, as shown below, but there has to be an easier way to do this.

```
if (Request::has('tags')) {
    $tags = Tag::find(explode(',', Request::get('tags')));
}else{
    $tags = null;
}
// Get all posts tagged with the tags
$jobs = \DB::table('post_tag');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $posts = $posts->orwhere('tag_id', $tag->id);
}
dd($posts->get());
```

This dumps an array of all posts that have any of the ID's, but I need to get an array of `post_id`s where it contains all `tag_id`s.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be a good idea to use `whereHas()` on the `Post` model to eager load the tags and get only the `Post`s which have at least one of those tags.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tags)
{
    $q->whereIn('id', $tags);
})->get();
```

Here, `$tags` would just be an array of tag id's. `$posts` would be a `Collection` of `Post`s.  To get the array of id's from it, you can simply do this...

```
$ids = $posts->lists('id');
```

Or instead of calling `get()` originally, use `...->lists('id')`

***Edit***

If you are looking for only those `Post`s which contain all of the tags, you want to pass some additional parameters to the `whereHas` function.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tags)
{
    $q->whereIn('id', $tags);
}, '=', count($tags))->get();
```

What will happen is it will only grab posts that have a number of tags attached equal to the count of the tags in the tags array.

If you use this approach, be sure your pivot table is managed correctly in that it is not possible to attach a certain tag to a certain model more than once.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Any idea on how to get posts that have all of the tags in `$tags`? Your idea works great to get all posts that have at least one of the tags. Should I loop through each `tag_id` and narrow down the query? At this point I just want to get it working, but I figured there was a relatively simple laravel way to do this.

Comment: Yeah there is a great way to do that, `whereHas` takes some additional parameters to handle just that thing, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Your updated answer is exactly what I needed. I've tried to follow laravel standards as much as I can, so I'm properly attaching and syncing the tags. Thanks again!

Comment: I usually put a composite primary key on the `tag_id` and `post_id` columns in the pivot table just to be 100% sure duplicates can never happen on those columns.  It can also be done with a unique key as well.

Comment: SQL Server older than 2008 doesn't properly sync pivot tables up using eloquent (multiple insert statements aren't supported), so I have to manually detach all tags and re-attach them, so there's no duplicates happening. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: Thank you from the end of 2017)