# Eloquent/October 'many-to-many' relation - how to search by related data?

Tags: eloquent, octobercms

Here's simplified view of Models and according columns from DB

```
Route
id

City 
id
name

RouteCityPivot
id
city_id
route_id
```

One Route can have only two related Cities. Let's say they are Berlin and Munich.
How can I find a route by the City names?

This code can find several routes *which has at least one* of the Cities:

```
$route = Route::whereHas('cities', function ($q) use ($from, $to){
            q->whereIn('name', [$from, $to]);
        })->get();
```

How can I find the route *which has exactly 2* of the given Cities? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872905/laravel-get-posts-with-multiple-tags)

The solution is

```
 $route = Route::whereHas('cities', function ($q) use ($cities){
            $q->whereIn('name', $cities);
        }, '=', count($cities))->get();
```